# Achicar la altura de nav materialize

Tags: css, html5, materialize, material-design

Tengo nav-bar de materialize

```
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css">

  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
 <nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <a href="" class="brand-logo" >KeyBiometric</a>
    <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li><a href="">ingresar</a></li>
      <li><a href="">registrar<span class="new badge">4</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="">informacion</a></li>
      <li><a href="">inicio</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

quiero achicar la altura como lo hago?

Comment: Quitale `card-panel`

Comment: @HectorSeguro si funciono, modifique mi pregunta.

Comment: Pero al modificar eso tienes que modificar tooodos los hijos de ese elemento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede cambiarlo de esta manera:

```css
@media (min-width: 500px) { /* si desea, cambiar tamaño de la pantalla en esta línea */
    nav {
        height: 45px !important;            /* Cambia el valor de lo que quieres */
        line-height: 45px !important;       /* Cambia el valor de lo que quieres */
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a href="" class="brand-logo" >KeyBiometric</a>
        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a href="">ingresar</a></li>
            <li><a href="">registrar<span class="new badge">4</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="">informacion</a></li>
            <li><a href="">inicio</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

He añadido las *media queries* en caso de que sólo desea cambiar el tamaño apenas en *desktops* o lo que sea, dependiendo de sus pensamientos al respecto. Ya estaba pensando en adelante.